# Understanding invariants using Euclid's algorithimn

Tags: algorithm, invariants

I'm having issues trying to understand the word "invariant" and "variant" and how it relates to programming in c. It's used a lot in my textbook and its mentioned quite often by my professor but I can't seem to properly understand it even after reading other replies on stack overflow.

Here's one statement my prof mentioned:

"Euclid’s gcd algorithm works because it maintains the invariant gcd(m, n) = gcd(n, r), in which r = m mod n"

I think this is the dumbed-down pseudo code for Euclid's GCD that is mentioned:

---

gcd(m, n) = gcd(n, r)

1. r = m % n
2. m = n
3. n = r

   ---

I'm confused on the invariant portion of the phrase. From Wikipedia it says the invariant is "a logical assertion that is held to always be true during a certain phase of execution". But to be honest I don't quite understand what they mean.

Why is gcd(m,n) = gcd(n,r) considered an invariant? Would someone be able to dumb down the phrase so people as uneducated as my self could understand why the following example is an invariant?

And is there any simple variant program example that someone could provide so I can see the difference between a variant and invariant? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm actually curious as to what definition of "variant" your professor is trying to teach you; usually when I see that I think "someone is just finding a different way of doing things"

Comment: They mean that the statement is always ("invariably") true, at that point in the program.

Comment: Thanks Rici, that makes a lot more sense. I think it was kind of a spur of the moment example. We didn't really cover variants or invariant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take Wikipedia definition, invariant would be "GCD of the current pair of numbers is the same as GCD of the original pair of numbers". The way we go from one pair to another one ({m,n} -> {n,m%n}) is, of course, part of the algorithm, but not really related to invariant.

So in these terms the algorithm could be described: every time we jump to an easier (smaller numbers) problem with *the same* answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered but does not seem to address the true meaning of invariance. An invariant is a property in a problem that does not change.

For example, consider the following puzzle: there is a chessboard with the squares in the diagonally opposite corners missing. Is it possible to tile the chessboard with dominos (a pair of squares, one black and one white). Now if you look at the problem, you can see that there is a fixed property: when a tile is removed, there is one black and one white square removed. Hence the invariant is the property: number of black squares == number of white squares. Hence we can conclude that the problem is unsolvable since the opposite squares are of the same color and we have a modified chessboard with unequal number of blacks and whites.

So basically what the professor is trying to do is determine a property that is unchanged for the lifetime of the problem and then use it.